# gdb in Code::Blocks failed to run

Tags: c++, windows, gdb, mingw, codeblocks

After debugging for some hours, I am unable to debug my project I'm making anymore for the following reasons.
(*It compiles smoothly without errors nor warnings from the compiler.*)

**Problem #1:**

> Error creating process d:\My
>       Documents\Downloads\CandyCrush\CandyCrush\bin\debug\CandyCrush.exe, 
>       (error 5).

**Solutions:**

1. I followed the suggestions
   [here](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=7552.0;prev_next=next) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999507/mingw-make-cant-handle-spaces-in-path),
   so I think it fixed one thing. (*'spaces' in environment path*)
2. Reboot the computer to ensure that the path is made available to all processes properly as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321980/yet-another-mingw-gcc-error-createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory). (*Although its somewhat not really related to my problem*)
3. Change the directory of my IDE along with the compiler.
4. Change the directory of the project I'm working on.
5. Delete and reinstall [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).
6. Delete and reinstall [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/).

And it changes the problem.

(*take note that I always try to debug and run after each solutions*)

**Problem #2:**

> Starting debugger: D:\cb\CodeBlocks\MingGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname  -quiet  -args D:/CandyCrush/CandyCrush/bin/Debug/CandyCrush.exe **failed**

**Solution:**

1. Configure manually the path of debugger from the IDE (*it says it can't find the file but it is there(?)*) so it does fixed it.

Aaaand the first problem return again, so I think I really mess up things here.

What could be the fix?

PS. I'm using [GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/)

**Edit**

Full (Debug) log

> Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5
>
> [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb: [debug]> set width 0 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
>
> [debug]> set height 0 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb: [debug]> set breakpoint
>
> pending on [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb: [debug]> set print asm-demangle on
>
> [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb: [debug]> set unwindonsignal on
>
> [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb: [debug]> set print elements 0
>
> [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb: [debug]> set new-console on [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
>
> [debug]> set disassembly-flavor att [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb: [debug]>
>
> catch throw [debug]Catchpoint 1 (throw) [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb: [debug]>
>
> source D:\cb\CodeBlocks\share\codeblocks/scripts/stl-views-1.0.3.gdb
>
> [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb: [debug]> directory D:/CandyCrush/CandyCrush/
>
> [debug]Source directories searched:
>
> D:/CandyCrush/CandyCrush;$cdir;$cwd [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb: [debug]> run
>
> [debug]Error creating process
>
> D:\CandyCrush\CandyCrush\bin\Debug\CandyCrush.exe, (error 5).
>
> [debug]Starting program:
>
> D:\CandyCrush\CandyCrush\bin\Debug\CandyCrush.exe
>
> [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
>
> Error creating process
>
> D:\CandyCrush\CandyCrush\bin\Debug\CandyCrush.exe, (error 5).
>
> [debug]> quit
>
> Debugger finished with status 0

Comment: I assume you're running on Windows - error 5 is access denied.  Is there actually a file at `D:\CandyCrush\CandyCrush\bin\Debug\CandyCrush.exe` and if so does it have any unusual permissions?  Why does the first error message in your question mention a different path than in the debug log, `d:\My Documents\Downloads\CandyCrush\CandyCrush\bin\debug\CandyCrush.exe`?

Comment: @MichaelBurr because I already changed its path to `no-spaces` one

Comment: Do you have an antivirus that might be interfering with running the CandyCrush.exe program?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Avira Free AV? Ahmm. I can run CandyCrush.exe in OS but not in gdb.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't good at all. After resting the IDE(compiler, debugger, editor) for some hours, it magically works again. I didn't close any application or reboot the computer.

Also It's because of *Game Guard* or *Anti Virus*