# MINGW, Code::Blocks - No such file or directory error when compiling c++

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, codeblocks

When I try to compile C++ programm in Code::blocks it gives me this error:

> -------------- Build: Debug in elcounter (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
>
> mingw32-g++.exe -Weffc++ -Wall -std=c++14 -fexceptions -Weffc++ -std=c++14 -g -I"C:\Users\Zahir\Box Sync\CPP projects\September_2k16\elcounter\" -c "C:\Users\Zahir\Box Sync\CPP projects\September_2k16\elcounter\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\main.o
>
> mingw32-g++.exe: error: **Sync\CPP:** No such file or directory
>
> mingw32-g++.exe: **error: projects\September_2k16**\elcounter\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o: No such file or directory
>
> mingw32-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files

I am using **MinGW g++** compiler.

Just for a test, I tried to compile simple "Hello, world" file and it gave me the same error.

Compiled the same "Hello, world" file in a command line using 
*"g++ test.cpp -o hello.exe"* and in worked just fine, so I believe the compiler is installed correctly.

The error seems to be related to spaces in a file path.

C:\Users\Zahir\Box Sync\CPP projects\September_2k16\elcounter\

> mingw32-g++.exe: error: **Sync\CPP:** No such file or directory
>
> mingw32-g++.exe: **error: projects\September_2k16**\elcounter\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o: No such file or directory

Might be a problem with a build system in Code::blocks? I tried to copy the command code::blocks using to a command line and it gave the same error. (**mingw32-g++.exe -Weffc++ -Wall** *etc.*)

EDIT: I don't want to change file path because "Box Sync" is used by the same name app that synchronizes file with a cloud.(box.com) The app doesn't support changing the main folders name and I'd prefer the project files stay synchronized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mingw make can't handle spaces in path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999507/mingw-make-cant-handle-spaces-in-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to remove all spaces from file and folder names in your project.

In your case it's the 'CPP projects' folder and 'box sync'

Comment: I guess so. But I would like to find other ways to solve this problem. As "box sync" is a synchronized folder using Box desktop app. And changing its name results in app redownloading all files again.

Comment: See the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999507/mingw-make-cant-handle-spaces-in-path you can create a symlink to a folder without spaces and keep your directory structure

Comment: Thank you. It did help me out.

`mklink /j "C:\newshortcut" "C:\Program Files\Directory with spaces"`

I also had to remake my project with a new path.