# Git pull if folder in remote contains spaces

Tags: git, mingw

I just want get pull of remote, but I can not do it correctly, because in remote repo appeared folder with space in name. Then after git pull I recieve message for all files in this folder, that git can't create it , and all this files put in unstaged changes as "deleted".
[image]

After pull this situation:

```
$ git status
    On branch develop
    Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
    Changes not staged for commit:
      (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
      (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    ../support/UIKit/Layouts/Product /ProductBodyLayout.swift
               (and other files)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I know root of this problem - command line, which use git (MINGW32), interprets space like delimiter, so that this does not happen, on Windows, we should use space in path with `\`. But I don't understand, what should I do exactly in the moment, 
that done git pull operation without any deleted files? I need remove this files out deleted, but I can't do checkout on any of this files, and `git add` moves files to staged.

If I try git add:

```
$ git add ../support/UIKit/Layouts/Product\ /ProductBodyLayout.swift
```

It add "deleted" file to staged:

```
 $ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    ../support/UIKit/Layouts/Product /ProductBodyLayout.swift

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    ../support/UIKit/Layouts/Product /ProductButtonLayout.swift
        (and other files)
```

If I try checkout I recieve an error:

```
 $ git checkout -- ../support/UIKit/Layouts/Product\ /ProductBodyLayout.swift
error: unable to create file support/UIKit/Layouts/Product /ProductBodyLayout.swift: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please **edit** your question and show the _exact_ Git commands you ran, and then highlight what is going wrong.

Comment: Done, I also highligth what is going wrong in git pull

Comment: Unforutnately, your edit does not do much to help, because you did not show what `git status` was right before you did that pull.  I don't think a `git pull` on a clean slate would cause that error.

Comment: I do not have any screen what show git status before git pull because it my routine operation with git. I just can said what before I just work in my branch and after finish work I commited my changes and just checkout on branch develop that get pull of remotes.
I dont change this problem folder with space, it new folder from remote.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix it so I'm posting this as comment for now. Try `git reset --hard`. Then `git pull`

Comment: Note: I only mention reset because your git status shows that you don't have any uncommitted files. If you have local changes you need to back them up first.

Comment: clebetman It doesnt fix ((
`$ git reset --hard
error: unable to create file support/UIKit/Layouts/Product /ProductBodyLayout.swift: No such file or directory
(and other files so on)
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.`
And `git reset --hard HEAD` does the same.

Comment: This appears to be a MinGW issue. Essentially, the version of Git you chose to use is not capable of dealing with this particular repository. Windows itself is not the problem and other versions of Git on Windows should work.

Comment: I dont understand what means 'the version of Git is not capabe of dealing with this particular repository'. I should update my Git? (at the moment is git version 2.13.2.windows.1)
Actually, I work with this repo about one year and all be right, 
until the folder name appeared a space.

Comment: My developers delete space in folder name and now is all right. But for further, issue dont solved (because it no solve, when I should ask and depends....

Answer (score 1):

Putting double quotes around the full file path should work:

```
git add "../support/UIKit/Layouts/Product /ProductBodyLayout.swift"
```

You could also escape the space:

```
git add ../support/UIKit/Layouts/Product\ /ProductBodyLayout.swift
```

But, while this gets around the immediate problem, moving forward you might want to avoid using file/path names which have characters which must be escaped.  This is because you will have to keep escaping like this.

If you want to discard the delete operation, then take the advice of the bash and use this:

```
git checkout -- "../support/UIKit/Layouts/Product /ProductBodyLayout.swift"
```

Comment: Not is not work, because how I said early, git add move this "deleted" files to staged as "deleted". And I said also that I can' checkout

Comment: What is your question here?  Are you asking for a workaround to the space in the file path, or are you asking about how to add/undo a deleted file?

Comment: I ask how I shoul do, that done `git pull` operation correcly. At the moment git can't recieve files where are spaces in paths and say me thah this files deleted.

Comment: No, that doesn't sound right.  `git pull` should have no trouble bringing in files, regardless of whether the path has spaces.  You need to narrow down your question to what you are actually asking.

Comment: Tim You probably work on Linux or Mac. On Windows we HAVE problems with spaces in paths.

Comment: No, I have been using Git on Windows for years and I never have seen the problem you are describing.

Comment: Could you say me please which command line use your git then?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the message from `git` carefully, it gives several suggestions. Probably the one you want is:

```
git checkout -- <file>...
```

Just be sure to put quotes around the file name. Then you can rename the file with `git mv` and `git commit`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as an issue with mingw of handling spaces. [Stack overflow question on mingw handling of spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999507/mingw-make-cant-handle-spaces-in-path#5999667).

You can use double quotes(") around the file name to handle this issue. Or copy the files manually and add them locally as new files and remove spaces, so that this issue does not occur. The problem is that all the history is gone for the file and treated as new file.

Comment: The OP does not have any file with spaces. Read the question again. SOMEONE ELSE (not the OP) upstream pushed files with spaces. The OP merely wants to pull files with spaces

Comment: slebetman. Yes, you correctly understood my description of the problem, thank you.

Comment: For my sorrow I can't edit this folder name because programmers say me that this can create problems. I think that they already use this path somewhere and it needs not only edit only folder name...  In general, for now it seems like I can't get changes from remote on this command line (I should works with repo on Mac or Linux or find other command line on Windows which correctly work with spaces in path) ...