# Codelite won't compile any program

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, g++

I am getting this error on my codelite IDE and it won't even compile or run a simple hello world program. I tried reinstalling codelite and Mingw compiler but that isn't working either. Does anyone know any potential fix/fixes?

Error: [image]

Comment: Take a look at this question. It seems that mingw has trouble with paths containing spaces: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999507/mingw-make-cant-handle-spaces-in-path

Comment: Space is the final frontier. No surprise that it has yet to be addressed.

Comment: Please try to post error output and code as text if possible: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mingw make can't handle spaces in path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999507/mingw-make-cant-handle-spaces-in-path)