# Why does start file in gitbash open the command prompt and not the file?

Tags: html, command-prompt, git-bash

When i am in my project folder and use the command `start index.html` it works perfectly and opens up the file in my browser, however, when I use `start new\ index.html` it opens up the command prompt. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if adding quotes would help, in a git bash session:

```
start "new\ index.html"
```

Since it is not working, I tested successfully, after reading "[mingw make can't handle spaces in path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61530575/6309)", and [using `cygpath`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html):

```
start $(cygpath -w -s "new index.html")
```

With:

```sh
cygpath -w -s "new index.html"
NEWIND~1.HTM
```

Comment: @Tony I have edited the answer with a working solution (I just tested it, it works)

Comment: @Tony Did you test my solution?